# BizTalk binding file import doesn't work

Tags: biztalk

We have upgraded a BizTalk 2006 application to 2013. After deploying this, we imported the binding file of 2006 (exported from 2006); it creates all ports, however it doesn't bind the orchestrations (host and ports). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue - binding file had a different assembly version than the deployed assemblies

Answer (score -1):

Well, probably you don't have those hosts and host instances, that you had before, or you haven't created handlers for adapters, that you use.
Guess you should create exactly same hosts and host instances as you had on BT 2006. And then specify exaclty same adapter handlers, that you had on BT 2006.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arsen, I traced the issue to wrong assembly version in binding file